# Configurar Firewal Servidor SQL

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-azure

Como configura a regra do firewal para não ficar pedindo atualização de um novo IP ?
Criei uma conta no azure e tenho um sistema que esta em teste e o servidor sql server de tempos em tempos pedi para atualizar o IP e quando acontece isso o sistema não acessa o banco de dados e tenho que sempre adicionar um novo range de IP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poderia esclarecer melhor o seu problema?

Answer (score 0):

A solução mais directa (se for possível) é colocar a maior gama possível:
0.0.0.0 - 255.255.255.255

Comment: @Renato Afonso vou tentar e assim que possível eu retorno, obrigado!